# How to use flexbox in a Material UI Select Component?

Tags: css, flexbox, material-ui

I am using material UI and trying to create a dropdown that has 2 columns:

[image: dropdown that has 2 columns]

My working code looks something like this:

```
<Select>
  <MenuItem>item 1</MenuItem>
  <MenuItem>item 2</MenuItem>
  <MenuItem>item 3</MenuItem>
  <MenuItem>item 4</MenuItem>
</Select>
```

I tried putting item 1 and item 2 into its own flexbox container using a react fragment, or div, and doing so breaks the functionality of the select dropdown - the items don't get selected when you click on the options

```
<Select>
  <div>
    <MenuItem>item 1</MenuItem>
    <MenuItem>item 2</MenuItem>
  </div>
  <div>
    <MenuItem>item 3</MenuItem>
    <MenuItem>item 4</MenuItem>
  </div>
</Select>
```

I want there to be two separate containers since I want to add scrollbars to each container as well.

Is there any way to keep the containers without breaking the select functionality?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to apply grid styling directly to the MuiList-root class of the popup. Make sure you remove your wrapping divs first.

```
.MuiList-root {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
 }
```